# Scanner/ Input Problems?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

My code doesn't work, even though I added a sentinel. It loops forever.

```
boolean exit = true;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList<String> inputData = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<Integer> outputData = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    while(sc.hasNext() && exit) {
        String aStr = sc.next();
        String sentinel = "0 0 0";
        if(aStr.equals(sentinel)){
            exit = false;
            System.out.println("Failed");
        }
        else{
            inputData.add(aStr);
        }
    }

    sc.close();
```

What is the cause of this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `next()` uses space as a delimiter which "breaks" the input `0 0 0` into 3 different inputs of `0`.

Replace:

```
String aStr = sc.next();
```

with:

```
String aStr = sc.nextLine();
```

and:

```
        if(aStr.equals(sentinel)){
            exit = false;
            System.out.println("Failed");
        }
```

with:

```
        if(aStr.equals(sentinel)){
            System.out.println("Failed");
            break;
        }
```

**Complete code:**

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
ArrayList<String> inputData = new ArrayList<String>();
while(sc.hasNext()) {
    String aStr = sc.nextLine();
    String sentinel = "0 0 0";
    if(aStr.equals(sentinel)){
        System.out.println("Failed");
        break;
    }
    else{
        inputData.add(aStr);
    }
}
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(inputData.toArray())); // for debug
sc.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Default delimiter of Scanner is whitespace. So the issue lies there.

```
 String aStr = sc.nextLine();
```

This will work.

You can also try something as:

```
String address = System.console().readLine("Enter your Address: ");
```

This will allow you to read the whole line. Hope this helps.